# how to know if a reboot will be required

Tags: apt, package-management, yum, zypper

Depending on your Linux version there are different commands to update the system from a repository.

What command is needed to `preview` whether a reboot will be required.... In other words - BEFORE an update, rather than after.

- for SLES/OpenSUSE?
- for Debian/Ubuntu?
- for RHEL/CentOS/Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

For Debian & Ubuntu, you could do an upgrade dry-run via `apt-get dist-upgrade -s` and look for a new kernel being installed. Except in very few cases, this should cover everything.

Exceptions I can think of:

- root or other critical partitions on a third-party kernel module that
  gets upgraded.
- grsec locking in the kernel, where some actions are
  not available until the reboot

Comment: thx for the answer. need to get some system(s) installed to test.